# Uploading an audio file obtained via getUserMedia() and Javascript to a server using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html5-audio

I have pieced together a Javascript audio recorder that grabs the user microphone via getUserMedia and records and outputs a .OGG file for download. Note this only works in Firefox, which is fine for me.

Rather than provide a download link I want the file to be uploaded to the server via PHP as soon as it stops recording. I'm not sure how I should be going about doing that. I have tried using a form to grab it from $_FILES but I can't figure out how to pre populate the form with the BLOB to submit.

Here is what I have so far. Any input on how to move this along to a server via PHP would be appreciated!

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <audio controls autoplay></audio>

                <a id="downloadLink" download="mediarecorder.ogg" name="mediarecorder.ogg" href></a>

                <p id="data"></p>



                <script >
                    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;


                    var constraints = {audio: true};
                    var audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
                    var dataElement = document.querySelector('#data');
                    var downloadLink = document.querySelector('a#downloadLink');


                    function errorCallback(error){
                      console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
                    }

                    var count = 0;
                    function startRecording(stream) {
                        log('Starting...');
                        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);



                        mediaRecorder.onerror = function(e){
                            log('Error: ' + e);
                        };


                        mediaRecorder.onstart = function(e){
                            log('Started');
                        };

                        mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e){
                            log('Stopped');
                        };

                        mediaRecorder.onwarning = function(e){
                            log('Warning: ' + e);
                        };

                        // parameter is number of milliseconds of data to return in a single Blob
                        mediaRecorder.start();

                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                            mediaRecorder.stop();
                        }, 2400000);
                    }

                    window.onload = function(){
                        if (typeof MediaRecorder === 'undefined' || !navigator.getUserMedia) {
                            alert('Sorry! This demo requires Firefox Nightly.');
                        } else {

                            window.onkeydown = function(e){ 
                                if ( e.keyCode == 82 ) { //R pressed
                                    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, startRecording, errorCallback);
                                } else if ( e.keyCode == 83 ) { // S pressed
                                    mediaRecorder.stop();

                                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
                                        log('Data available...');
                                        count++;
                                        if (count > 1) {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        console.log(e);
                                        audioElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
                                        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.data); //Audio BLOB
                                        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download ogg audio file";


                                    };

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };


                    function log(message){
                        dataElement.innerHTML = message + '<br>' + dataElement.innerHTML ;
                    }


                </script>


            </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons in most browsers it is not allowed to pre fill an html upload element. Is the ogg file stored locally (on the client). If it is stored on the webserver an option could be to post the (public available) url to a php script and open it in by using file_get_contents.